# Getting error sp2-0310 when using "@@" (double "at" sign) command

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a folder structure similar to

```
/Release_script/
  install.sql
/common_code/
  error_handling.sql
/Reporting/
  fancy_report1.sql
  fancy_report2.sql
  some_code_to_include.sql
```

The install.sql script includes the lines

```
@../Reporting/fancy_report1.sql
@../Reporting/fancy_report2.sql
```

fancy_report1.sql and fancy_report2.sql both start with the line

```
@@../common_code/error_handling.sql
```

They also both include other `/Reporting/` files, ie `@@some_code_to_include.sql`

As documented within "SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference", the [@@ (double "at" sign)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1006822)

> Runs a script. This command is almost identical to the @ ("at" sign)
>   command. **It is useful for running nested scripts because it has the
>   additional functionality of looking for the specified script in the
>   same path or url as the script from which it was called**. Only the url
>   form is supported in iSQL*Plus.

When I open sqlplus in `/Release_script/` and attempt to run `install.sql`, I get the error

> SP2-0310: unable to open file "../common_code/error_handling.sql"

If I change fancy_report1.sql's reference to `@../common_code/error_handling.sql`, then execute fancy_report1.sql directly from the `/Reporting/` folder, it works.

**What commands should I use to run commands from the starting point of the calling file (ie `fancy_report1.sql`) and *not* from the starting point of the working directory (ie, `/Release_script/`)?** Why does the `@@` command seem to behave exactly like the `@` command?

For what it's worth:

```
sqlplus -S /nolog<<EOF
prompt &_SQLPLUS_RELEASE
```

Yields:

```
1102000100
```

Comment: Seems to work for me.  Have you checked your directory and file permissions?

Comment: @tale852150 ... file permissions? I'm using Windows 7...

Comment: Shouldn't you be using backslashes for path separators on Windows 7?

Comment: @JeromyFrench ok, then folder permissions.  I thought "file" because I saw the forward slashes in the question and no drive letters.

Comment: @mustaccio: I was thinking about that, too...but the first path (`@../Reporting/fancy_report.sql`) works, and it uses forward slashes, so I assumed that sqlplus does some magic to make it work.

Comment: @tale852150: FWIW, if I change fancy_report1.sql's reference to `@../common_code/error_handling.sql` (one @ vs @@), then execute fancy_report1.sql directly from the `/Reporting/` folder, it works. I would think that rules out cases-sensitivity, incorrect pathing, and permissions. This really boils down to why `@@` doesn't work outside of the calling file's folder!

Comment: Try my suggestion / answer and use absolute paths.  It's all I can see at this point that would be a solution.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say it's your version of SQL*Plus that doesn't like relative paths using @@.

This link: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ says "The @@ reference does not support relative directory references such as @@dir/file.sql or @@./file.sql." but it worked with my version.

I did the same setup as you described and ran the scripts using SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 and it ran fine. (The only difference is that I made the error_handling.sql script generate the text "COMMON_CODE\ERROR_HANDLING SCRIPT".)

I set my working directory to be Release_script and ran the install file:

```
C:\tmp\Release_script>sqlplus <un/pwd> @install.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jun 8 15:16:00 2016

MSG
---------------------------------
COMMON_CODE\ERROR_HANDLING SCRIPT


MSG
---------------------------------
COMMON_CODE\ERROR_HANDLING SCRIPT
```

Answer (score 0):

From the SQL*Plus documentation:

```
    @@ (double "at" sign)

Runs a script. This command is similar to the @ ("at" sign) command.
It is useful for running nested scripts because it looks for the specified
script in the same path as the script from which it was called.
```

Hopefully, the second half of that final sentence *may* be the clue to your issue.
If so, you *may* need to use absolute versus relative path names.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to recreate the issue on Red Hat Linux 6.7 or Windows 7.  Here is my Windows session ( I just use `select sysdate - 1 from dual;` in the file `error_handling.sql`):

[image]

So my suggestion is to use absolute path names.

SQL*Plus version (on Windows 7):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What version of sqlplus do you run?

Comment: See updated answer that now includes version of SQL*Plus for Windows environment.